# Boost Spirit optional parser and backtracking

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

Why this parser leave `'b'` in attributes, even if option wasn't matched?

```
using namespace boost::spirit::qi;

std::string str = "abc";

auto a = char_("a");
auto b = char_("b");
qi::rule<std::string::iterator, std::string()> expr;
expr = +a >> -(b >> +a);

std::string res;

bool r = qi::parse(
        str.begin(),
        str.end(),
        expr >> lit("bc"),
        res
);
```

It parses successfully, but res is `"ab"`.

If parse `"abac"` with expr alone, option is matched and attribute is `"aba"`.

Same with `"aac"`, option doesn't start to match and attribute is `"aa"`.

But with `"ab"`, attribute is `"ab"`, even though b gets backtracked, and, as in example, matched with next parser.

**UPD**

With `expr.name("expr");` and `debug(expr);` I got

```
<expr>
  <try>abc</try>
  <success>bc</success>
  <attributes>[[a, b]]</attributes>
</expr>
```

Comment: The behavior changed in X3 where optional parser always creates a temporary to parse into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, it's [UB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) to use the `auto` variables to keep the expression templates, because they hold references to the temporaries `"a"` and `"b"` **<sup>[1]</sup>**.

Instead write

```
expr = +qi::char_("a") >> -(qi::char_("b") >> +qi::char_("a"));
```

or, if you insist:

```
auto a = boost::proto::deep_copy(qi::char_("a"));
auto b = boost::proto::deep_copy(qi::char_("b"));
expr = +a >> -(b >> +a);
```

---

Now noticing the `>> lit("bc")` part hiding in the `parse` call, suggests you may expect backtracking to on succesfully matched tokens when a parse failure happens down the road.

That doesn't happen: Spirit generates PEG grammars, and always greedily matches from left to right.

---

On to the sample given, `ab` results, even though backtracking **does** occur, the effects on the attribute are not rolled back without `qi::hold`: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17771944b428cb30)**

Container attributes are passed along by ref and the effects of previous (successful) expressions is ***not*** rolled back, unless you tell Spirit too. This way, you can "pay for what you use" (as copying temporaries all the time would be costly).

See e.g.

- [boost::spirit::qi duplicate parsing on the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869978/boostspiritqi-duplicate-parsing-on-the-output/13875183#13875183)
- [Understanding Boost.spirit's string parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959270/understanding-boost-spirits-string-parser/21960981#21960981)
- [Boost spirit revert parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23953804/boost-spirit-revert-parsing/23955133#23955133)

```
<a>
  <try>abc</try>
  <success>bc</success>
  <attributes>[a]</attributes>
</a>
<a>
  <try>bc</try>
  <fail/>
</a>
<b>
  <try>bc</try>
  <success>c</success>
  <attributes>[b]</attributes>
</b>
<a>
  <try>c</try>
  <fail/>
</a>
<bc>
  <try>bc</try>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</bc>
Success: 'ab'
```

---

**<sup>[1]</sup>** see here:

- [Assigning parsers to auto variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023779/assigning-parsers-to-auto-variables/22027181#22027181)
- [Generating Spirit parser expressions from a variadic list of alternative parser expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177184/generating-spirit-parser-expressions-from-a-variadic-list-of-alternative-parser/16181550#16181550)
- [boost spirit V2 qi bug associated with optimization level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763665/boost-spirit-v2-qi-bug-associated-with-optimization-level/20766909#20766909)

Comment: But, I don't get it, you use binary minus? That's different language, isn't it?

Comment: @MikhailCheshkov I was just noticing this typo. **Updated** the answer. Excuse my mistake :/

Comment: I expect backtracking on non-matched characters - option will fail if no a was found after b, so b will not be consumed, and it will be matched by `lit("bc")`.

Comment: And I've done it with `hold` on option content, thanks for links!

Comment: @MikhailCheshkov I was still editing the answer. Sorry for delays, I'm having to divide attention here. I'll be done sone. [tester here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17771944b428cb30)

Answer (score 2):

Quoting @sehe from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959270/understanding-boost-spirits-string-parser/21960981) SO question

> A string attribute is a container attribute and many elements could be
>   assigned into it by different parser subexpressions. Now for
>   efficiency reasons, Spirit doesn't rollback the values of emitted
>   attributes on backtracking.

So, I've put optional parser on hold, and it's done.

```
expr = +qi::char_("a") >> -(qi::hold[qi::char_("b") >> +qi::char_("a")]);
```

For more information see mentioned question and [hold docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/hold.html)

Comment: That info is right in my answer. Mmmm. Maybe because I didn't show the usage of `hold` there. Ah well, +1 (thanks for putting up with my absent mindedness)