# How to use the qi::hold[] Parser directive. (Issue with attribute type for boost::swap)

Tags: c++, boost, swap, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have a parser that parses into a `boost::variant<int, double, std::string>`

```
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
using namespace std;

typedef map<string,  boost::variant<int, double, string> > namevalue;
typedef pair<string, boost::variant<int, double, string> > namevaluepair;

template <typename Iterator>
struct keys_and_values2
    :   grammar<Iterator, namevalue(), ascii::blank_type>
{
    keys_and_values2()
        :   keys_and_values2::base_type(start)
    {
        start %= query >> qi::eoi;
        query =  +pair;
        value =  qi::int_ | qi::double_ | qi::lexeme[+(qi::char_ - qi::eol)] ;
        pair  =  key >> qi::lit(':') >> value >> qi::eol;
        key   =  qi::char_("a-zA-Z_") >> *qi::char_("a-zA-Z_0-9");
    }
    qi::rule<Iterator, namevalue(), ascii::blank_type> start;
    qi::rule<Iterator, namevalue(), ascii::blank_type> query;
    qi::rule<Iterator, namevaluepair(), ascii::blank_type> pair;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), ascii::blank_type> key;
    qi::rule<Iterator, boost::variant<int, double, string>(), ascii::blank_type> value;
};
```

the input to parse is here:

```
Sarai    :    52.731199473801
Jamiya   :    Jelly Drop
Clara    :    -92.408605869885
Janelle  :    132349223
Briley   :    -40.905352495602
```

This fails on the first line "Sarai". If I reverse the parsing of double and int like this:

```
value =  qi::double_ | qi::int_ | qi::lexeme[+(qi::char_ - qi::eol)] ;
```

It works fine, but the integer value of "Janelle" is parsed as double. Following the [BOOST FAQ](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/doc-addendum/faq/) and the [BOOST documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/hold.html), I would like to use qi::hold[] like this:

```
value =  qi::hold[qi::int_] | qi::hold[qi::double_] | qi::lexeme[+(qi::char_ - qi::eol)] ;
```

But with this, I get a message about missing function: `swap()`. This is actually documented in the boost docs (note). But the explanation is *very terse*. I am unable to find the correct attribute type for this swap function. Can anybody help here?

Compiler message here:

```
E:\Boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/spirit/home/support/attributes.hpp(1036) : error C2784: 'void boost::spirit::swap(boost::spirit::multi_pass<T,Policies> &,boost::spirit::multi_pass<T,Policies> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'boost::spirit::multi_pass<T,Policies> &' from 'int'
```

---

**Update**
The [answer of sehe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30073193/4823151) works with the data above. However If I change the input to the following:

```
Sarai    :    52.731199473801
Jamiya   :    Jelly Drop
Clara    :    -92.408605869885
Rebekah  :    240ad9beb53bbfafcd5
Janelle  :    132349223
Cloe     :    456ABCabvc
Briley   :    -40.905352495602
```

I'll have a problem with the "Rebekah" value. I also see that the order in which the values are evaluated is important. This time, the issue is not with the `double` value anymore, it is between the `int` and the `string`. I would like to implement something like this: (policy?)

1. everything that has only digits, an optional minus sign and contains a dot is a `double`
2. everything that has only digits and an optional minus sign is `int`
3. everything else is `std::string`

---

**Solution**
Sometimes, it is more important to understand the question than the problem.

The issue was not the parser policy, it was my definition of the parsing rules (see above). Rule 3 "everything else" actually includes: "everything up to EOL". Therefore all three alternatives in the rule for `value` have to match this:

```
value =   strict_double >> qi::eol
        | qi::int_ >> qi::eol
        | qi::lexeme[+(qi::char_ - qi::eol)] >> qi::eol;
```

With this change, [sehe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30073193/4823151) just works like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold is not used for this.

Think about it: how would it help? It won't make the integer branch not match, so it will still fail to parse, and `hold` doesn't revert anything.

`hold[]` is mainly useful for container attributes¹, where partial parses could have modified the attribute. Containers usually already have swap implemented. You were barking up the wrong tree here

> ¹ including strings, see e.g. 
> <sub>• [Understanding Boost.spirit's string parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959270/understanding-boost-spirits-string-parser/21960981?s=2|0.0000#21960981)
>   
> • [boost::spirit::qi duplicate parsing on the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869978/boostspiritqi-duplicate-parsing-on-the-output/13875183?s=3|0.0000#13875183)
>   
> • [Boost spirit revert parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23953804/boost-spirit-revert-parsing/23955133?s=5|0.0000#23955133)
>   
> • [Boost Spirit optional parser and backtracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185900/boost-spirit-optional-parser-and-backtracking/26186191?s=7|0.0000#26186191)</sub>

---

#### Solving the problem:

You can use the strict real policy to parse only real values as double.

```
value =  strict_double | qi::int_ | qi::lexeme[+(qi::char_ - qi::eol)] ;

// with
qi::real_parser<double, qi::strict_real_policies<double> > strict_double;
```

See also [Parse int or double using boost spirit (longest_d)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261502/parse-int-or-double-using-boost-spirit-longest-d/13268320#13268320) for some unit tests

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54871b6a50c95cc4)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <map>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

typedef boost::variant<int, double, std::string> value_t;
typedef std::map<std::string, value_t> namevalue;
typedef std::pair<std::string, value_t> namevaluepair;

template <typename Iterator>
struct keys_and_values2
    :   qi::grammar<Iterator, namevalue(), ascii::blank_type>
{
    keys_and_values2() : keys_and_values2::base_type(start)
    {
        start %= query >> qi::eoi;
        query =  +pair;
        value =  strict_double | qi::int_ | qi::lexeme[+(qi::char_ - qi::eol)] ;
        pair  =  key >> qi::lit(':') >> value >> qi::eol;
        key   =  qi::char_("a-zA-Z_") >> *qi::char_("a-zA-Z_0-9");

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(query)(value)(pair)(key))
    }
  private:
    qi::real_parser<double, qi::strict_real_policies<double> > strict_double;
    qi::rule<Iterator, namevalue(),     ascii::blank_type> start;
    qi::rule<Iterator, namevalue(),     ascii::blank_type> query;
    qi::rule<Iterator, namevaluepair(), ascii::blank_type> pair;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(),   ascii::blank_type> key;
    qi::rule<Iterator, value_t(),       ascii::blank_type> value;
};

int main() {
    typedef boost::spirit::istream_iterator It;
    It f(std::cin >> std::noskipws), l;

    keys_and_values2<It> g;
    namevalue data;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l,g,ascii::blank,data);

    if (ok) {
        std::cout << "Parse succeeded:\n";
        for(auto& p : data)
            std::cout << "\t'" << p.first << "'\t-> " << p.second << "\n";
    } else
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

    if (f!=l)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Parse succeeded:
    'Briley'    -> -40.9054
    'Clara' -> -92.4086
    'Jamiya'    -> Jelly Drop
    'Janelle'   -> 132349223
    'Sarai' -> 52.7312
```

And the debug info (if enabled)

```
<start>
<try>Sarai    :    52.731</try>
<query>
    <try>Sarai    :    52.731</try>
    <pair>
    <try>Sarai    :    52.731</try>
    <key>
        <try>Sarai    :    52.731</try>
        <success>:    52.731199473801</success>
        <attributes>[[S, a, r, a, i]]</attributes>
    </key>
    <value>
        <try>    52.731199473801\n</try>
        <success>\nJamiya   :    Jelly</success>
        <attributes>[52.7312]</attributes>
    </value>
    <success>Jamiya   :    Jelly </success>
    <attributes>[[[S, a, r, a, i], 52.7312]]</attributes>
    </pair>
    <pair>
    <try>Jamiya   :    Jelly </try>
    <key>
        <try>Jamiya   :    Jelly </try>
        <success>:    Jelly Drop\nClar</success>
        <attributes>[[J, a, m, i, y, a]]</attributes>
    </key>
    <value>
        <try>    Jelly Drop\nClara</try>
        <success>\nClara    :    -92.4</success>
        <attributes>[[J, e, l, l, y,  , D, r, o, p]]</attributes>
    </value>
    <success>Clara    :    -92.40</success>
    <attributes>[[[J, a, m, i, y, a], [J, e, l, l, y,  , D, r, o, p]]]</attributes>
    </pair>
    <pair>
    <try>Clara    :    -92.40</try>
    <key>
        <try>Clara    :    -92.40</try>
        <success>:    -92.40860586988</success>
        <attributes>[[C, l, a, r, a]]</attributes>
    </key>
    <value>
        <try>    -92.408605869885</try>
        <success>\nJanelle  :    13234</success>
        <attributes>[-92.4086]</attributes>
    </value>
    <success>Janelle  :    132349</success>
    <attributes>[[[C, l, a, r, a], -92.4086]]</attributes>
    </pair>
    <pair>
    <try>Janelle  :    132349</try>
    <key>
        <try>Janelle  :    132349</try>
        <success>:    132349223\nBrile</success>
        <attributes>[[J, a, n, e, l, l, e]]</attributes>
    </key>
    <value>
        <try>    132349223\nBriley</try>
        <success>\nBriley   :    -40.9</success>
        <attributes>[132349223]</attributes>
    </value>
    <success>Briley   :    -40.90</success>
    <attributes>[[[J, a, n, e, l, l, e], 132349223]]</attributes>
    </pair>
    <pair>
    <try>Briley   :    -40.90</try>
    <key>
        <try>Briley   :    -40.90</try>
        <success>:    -40.90535249560</success>
        <attributes>[[B, r, i, l, e, y]]</attributes>
    </key>
    <value>
        <try>    -40.905352495602</try>
        <success>\n</success>
        <attributes>[-40.9054]</attributes>
    </value>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[[B, r, i, l, e, y], -40.9054]]</attributes>
    </pair>
    <pair>
    <try></try>
    <key>
        <try></try>
        <fail/>
    </key>
    <fail/>
    </pair>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[[[B, r, i, l, e, y], -40.9054], [[C, l, a, r, a], -92.4086], [[J, a, m, i, y, a], [J, e, l, l, y,  , D, r, o, p]], [[J, a, n, e, l, l, e], 132349223], [[S, a, r, a, i], 52.7312]]]</attributes>
</query>
<success></success>
<attributes>[[[[B, r, i, l, e, y], -40.9054], [[C, l, a, r, a], -92.4086], [[J, a, m, i, y, a], [J, e, l, l, y,  , D, r, o, p]], [[J, a, n, e, l, l, e], 132349223], [[S, a, r, a, i], 52.7312]]]</attributes>
</start>
```

---

Comment: Thanks a lot! I still have a lot to learn ;-) 
But please have a look at my update to the question. is there something like a `strict_integer_policy` ?